# Proper Python library structure / circular references

Tags: python, coding-style

I have a project with two classes with class methods (I call them helper classes):

```
userService.py

companyService.py
```

I often reached the point where I need the function of the user service in a company service and vice versa.

Of course then I will get into trouble with circular references.

Is there a neat solution to get this done without losing the separation of the code?

Answer (score 2):

Put what is common into a common module:

```
dir moudle:
    __init__.py # -> Put common stuff here 
    userService.py
    companyService.py
```

Also, in Python good style guidelines recommend naming your files in snake_case, for example, `user_service.py` instead of `userCase.py` (read about [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to solve your problem if you want to maintain separation of concerns.

Problem:
Circular references develop when you use imports like this

```
from module import method
```

instead change the import line to

```
import module
```

and when you want to use the method() use:

```
module.method()
```

It's a little more verbose but you won't have the circular import problem.